# restore views state after reStart

Tags: android, view

When pressing home key, the app goes to the background and when I bring it to the front again, some buttons loose their visibility and text states.How can I fix this?, **Activity reStart** gets called but not the **onCreate** thus 
the **savedInstanceState** is not available. The views have their id defined in xml and their visibility and text get changed in code.

Comment: `when I bring it to the front again, some buttons loose their visibility and text states` do you mean in ideal case or are you killing the app process?

Comment: Just override back button in activity so that your task will will move back. moveTaskToBack(true);

Comment: The app is not being killed because fragment views are still intact. onDestroy is not called. onRestart gets called.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this which seams to work for me. not sure if this is the "right" way to do it.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mViewState = new Bundle();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mViewState.putInt("mainBtVis", mMainButtons_LL.getVisibility());
}

@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    int vis = mViewState.getInt("mainBtVis");
    mYes_Bt.setVisibility((vis == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : vis == 4 ? View.INVISIBLE : View.GONE);    
}
```